# SQL CASE statement (Multiple-to-one)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, case-statement

From the following table of multiple flower types in multiple locations:

```
Location1....Lantana
Location1....Lantana
Location1....Alba
Location1....Alba
Location2....Lantana
Location2....Gallica
Location2....Gallica
Location3....Noisette
Location3....Noisette
```

I want to create 4 new columns of (Boolean) CASE statements for the 4 different flower types, each column returns '1' if at least one of the flowers in that location has 1 of the 4 types.

### Example:

If Location1 has only 50 Lantanas and 50 Albas

and Location2 has 20 Lantanas , 30 Gallicas

### Desired output Table

```
Location#  |  Total # of flowers  | # of Lantana  |  Alba  |  Gallica  |  Noisette
Location1...........100.................1...............1............0.........0
Location2...........50..................1...............0............1.........0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method:

```
select location, count(*) as num_flowers,
       max(case when flow = 'Lantana' then 1 else 0 end) as Lantana,
       max(case when flow = 'Alba' then 1 else 0 end) as Alba,
       max(case when flow = 'Gallica' then 1 else 0 end) as Gallica,
       max(case when flow = 'Noisette' then 1 else 0 end) as Noisette
from t
group by location;
```

Answer (score 1):

Somehow I always try to avoid using `CASE` (in cases when I can of course) at least for the reason that `CASE` statement makes query look heavy and bushy

So below is the `CASE`-less version :o)

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT location, COUNT(*) AS num_flowers,
   SIGN(COUNTIF(flower = 'Lantana')) AS Lantana,
   SIGN(COUNTIF(flower = 'Alba')) AS Alba,
   SIGN(COUNTIF(flower = 'Gallica')) AS Gallica,
   SIGN(COUNTIF(flower = 'Noisette')) AS Noisette
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY location
-- ORDER BY location
```

Note: `SIGN` just makes 1 or 0 out of actual count (as per your requirement in question). SO if you remove SIGN() - yo will get actual count - which can be more useful than just 0/1

You can test / play with it using dummy data from your example as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'Location1' location, 'Lantana' flower UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Location1', 'Lantana' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Location1', 'Alba' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Location1', 'Alba' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Location2', 'Lantana' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Location2', 'Gallica' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Location2', 'Gallica' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Location3', 'Noisette' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Location3', 'Noisette' 
)
SELECT location, COUNT(*) AS num_flowers,
   SIGN(COUNTIF(flower = 'Lantana')) AS Lantana,
   SIGN(COUNTIF(flower = 'Alba')) AS Alba,
   SIGN(COUNTIF(flower = 'Gallica')) AS Gallica,
   SIGN(COUNTIF(flower = 'Noisette')) AS Noisette
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY location
ORDER BY location
```

Comment: Thanks @Mikhail ! It's awesome to have a different way around if we want to avoid using CASE.